# How to extract only the English words and leaving the Devanagari words in bash script?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

The text file is like this,

```
#एक
1के
अंकगणित8IU
अधोरेखाunderscore
$thatऔर
%redएकyellow
$चिह्न
अंडरस्कोर@_
```

The desired text file should be like,

```
#
1
8IU
underscore
$that
%redyellow
$
@_
```

This is what I have tried so far, using `awk`

`awk -F"[अ-ह]*" '{print $1}' filename.txt`
And the output that I am getting is,

```
#
1


$that
%red
$
```

and using this `awk -F"[अ-ह]*" '{print $1,$2}' filename.txt` and I am getting an output like this,

```
# 
1 े
 ं
 ो
$that 
%red yellow
$ ि
 ं
```

Is there anyway to solve this in bash script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using perl:

```sh
$ perl -CSD -lpe 's/\p{Devanagari}+//g' input.txt
#
1
8IU
underscore
$that
%redyellow
$
@_
```

`-CSD` tells perl that standard streams and any opened files are encoded in UTF-8. `-p` loops over input files printing each line to standard output after executing the script given by `-e`. If you want to modify the file in place, add the `-i` option.

The regular expression matches any codepoints assigned to the Devanagari script in the Unicode standard and removes them. Use `\P{Devanagari}` to do the opposite and remove the non-Devanagari characters.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` you can do:

```
awk '{sub(/[^\x00-\x7F]+/, "")} 1' file
#
1
8IU
underscore
$that
%redyellow
```

- See documentation: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Bracket-Expressions.html

> using `[\x00-\x7F]`.
> This matches all values numerically between zero and 127, which is the defined range of the ASCII character set. Use a complemented character list `[^\x00-\x7F]` to match any single-byte characters that are not in the ASCII range.

Answer (score 0):

`tr` is  a very good fit for this task:

```sh
LC_ALL=C tr -c -d '[:cntrl:][:graph:]' < input.txt
```

It sets the POSIX C locale environment so that only US English character set is valid.

Then instructs `tr` to `-d` delete `-c` complement `[:cntrl:][:graph:]`, control and drawn characters classes (those not control or visible) characters. Since it is sets all the locale setting to `C`, all non-US-English characters are discarded.